# Bounded linear operator on Banach space having finite or infinite dimension.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ is a Banach space. Does space of bounded linear operator $B(X)$ under operator norm can be Hilbert space? . We have that if $X$ is Hilbert space then $B(X)$ is not Hilbert space if dimension of $X$ is greater than 1.

Comment: that last statement is not true. take for example $X=L^2([0,1])$

Comment: You asked a similar question, but closed https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3831545/bounded-linear-operator-on-finite-or-infinite-dimension-banach-space

Comment: I do not understand the  @alphaomega comment.  If $X=L^2([0,1])$ then $B(X)$ is not Hilbert space.  We can easily find a subspace of $B(X)$ (with  the operator norm) isometric to $l^\infty$.  My guess is, if $X$ has dimension $\ge 2$ then $B(X)$ has a subspace isometric to $2$-dimensional $l^\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

What you are actually asking is if the operator norm is induced from an inner product. It is true that if $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ is a normed space then $\|\cdot\|$ is induced from an inner product if and only if it satisfies the parallelogram law, i.e. if and only if $\|x+y\|^2+\|x-y\|^2=2\|x\|^2+2\|y\|^2$ for all $x,y\in X$.

For your question, we have to check whether the operator norm on $B(X)$ satifies the parallelogram law. Assume that $X$ has dimension greater than two and pick a subspace $Y$ of dimension $2$. Since all the operators $Y\to Y$ are bounded when extended by $0$ to $X$, it is easy to check that $B(X)$ will contain isometrically a copy of $B(\mathbb{C}^2)\cong M_2(\mathbb{C})$, but the matrix norm on 2x2 matrices does not satisfy the parallelogram law.